SQLite memory database state not shared between integration test and controller in .NET Core with xUnit
I've been following the official .Net documentation for integration tests, and I have an issue, where my Sqlite database that I access in the tests is different from the one in my controller. Here's an example:
/// IntegrationTest.cs
public class ClientTests : IClassFixture<InvoicerApplicationFactory> {

[Fact]
public async void Post_ShouldCreateClient()
{
    var client = await CreateClientWithAuth(); // Here we create a user in the database
    var content = JsonEncode( ... );

    var user = await userManager.Users.ToListAsync(); // List with one user
    Assert.Single( user ); // Pass: User exists

    var result = await client.PostAsync( "/Api/Client", content ); // Fail: Database empty
}


In my controller, if I ask for the list of users, I get an empty list, even though in the test it was just confirmed that the user exists.
/// Controller.cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ClientDto>> Create( [Bind]CreateClient model )
{
    /// ...
    var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync(); // Empty list???
}

This is how I register my test services:
public class InvoicerApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private SqliteConnection? _connection;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost( IWebHostBuilder builder )
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices( services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<InvoicerDbContext> >();
            services.RemoveAll<DbConnection>();

            // Create the connection to database
            _connection = new SqliteConnection( "DataSource=:memory:" );
            _connection.Open();

            services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>( container => _connection );

            services.RemoveAll<InvoicerDbContext>();
            services.AddDbContext<InvoicerDbContext>( ( container, options ) =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite( _connection );
            } );

            // Migrate the database
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var scope = sp.CreateScope();
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<InvoicerDbContext>();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        } );

        builder.UseEnvironment( "Testing" );
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        base.Dispose( disposing );
        _connection?.Dispose();
    }
}

Finally, this is what my CreateClientWithAuth() function looks like, it's a function I use to create a client with authentication mocking and a default user.
protected async Task<HttpClient> CreateClientWithAuth( string email = "admin@test.com", string password = "admin" )
{
    return CreateClientWithAuth( await CreateUser( email, password ) );
}

protected HttpClient CreateClientWithAuth( User authenticatedUser )
{
    this.authenticatedUser = authenticatedUser;

    var client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder( builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices( services =>
        {
            services.AddAuthentication( defaultScheme: "TestScheme" )
                .AddScheme<TestAuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                    "TestScheme", options => {
                        options.DefaultUser = authenticatedUser; 
                    } );
        } );
    } )
        .CreateClient();

    return client;
} 

Additionally, when I use a file instead :memory: as source, the issue disappears, so I assume it's the problem of tests not sharing the same Sqlite connection with the rest of the project. My tests are located in a different project than the Program.cs file, but they are in the same solution and are referenced.
Edit:
Here is how I register Identity:
/// In Program.cs
services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<InvoicerDbContext>();

In controller userManager is retrieved by using DI, in the tests, I use this code:
// factory is InvoicerApplicationFactory, passed through the constructor of the test class:
public ApiTest( InvoicerApplicationFactory appfactory )
{
    factory = appfactory;
    userManager = factory.Services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
}


Try create database exactly after .CreateClient() var sb factory.Services.GetRequiredService<InvoicerDbContext>() ... ,

Didn't seem to work, still two different databases in test class and controller... I feel like the issue must be with the connection itself, that it maybe gets duplicated and opens two databases in memory.

We can't see where userManager from the test and _userManager from the controller are coming from, so it's hard to tell. Anyway, they must be different instances, whilst you were expecting them to be the same. Maybe check your DI if that's where they are coming from. In case of :memory:, they must follow the singleton pattern. In case of :file:, it wouldn't matter because data would be read from the same source stored on the disk.

I added information about UserManager. In Program.cs, I call AddIdentityApiEndpoints function, and retrieve UserManager using DI. In test classes, I use factory.Services.GetRequiredService.

I think Microsoft's SQLite data provider doesn't support shared mode.
